# ESP8266 has problems receiving udp packets

Tags: arduino, udp, wifi, esp32, arduino-esp8266

My WeMos D1 Mini is running a script that is supposed to perform certain actions if it receives certain strings in udp packets.

It works most of the time, but sometimes it just doesn't respond to anything.
Usually it's enough to just wait a few minutes or send the packet a couple of times. My guess is that it might go into some kind of deep sleep. Sometimes the only thing that helps is to restart it.

I tried implementing a watchdog but that didn't really work (but that's a separate issue) and i'm not sure if it would even solve the problem.
I'm sending the packets through Netcat and the WiFi strength is ok (but not great).
Everything is on the local network.

Please take a look at my code and check it for mistakes/improvements.

```c
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUDP.h>

#define SSID "XXX"
#define PASSWORD "XXX"
#define PORT XXX

WiFiUDP udpServer;

char MESSAGE[] = "message";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(SSID, PASSWORD);
  wifiStrength();

  udpServer.begin(PORT);

  delay(100);
}

void wifiStrength(){
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      Serial.println("no wifi, reconnecting...");
      delay(3000);
      WiFi.begin(SSID, PASSWORD);
    }
    long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
    Serial.print("connected, RSSI:");
    Serial.println(rssi);
  }

void loop() {
  if (udpServer.parsePacket()) {
    char receiveBuffer[WIFICLIENT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE + 1];
    udpServer.read(receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer) - 1);

    if (strstr(receiveBuffer, MESSAGE)) {
      Serial.println("do stuff...");
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Wireshark or tcpdump or a similar tool to verify that the packets you're expecting to see have been sent? How fast are you sending them? Also have you tried a version of your code that always prints a debug message when it gets a UDP packet, without the `strstr()` check?

Comment: According to Wireshark the packets were sent every time, but i'll keep sniffing. I don't have that println without the strstr() at the moment because the arduino is usually not plugged into the pc and it doesn't have any persistent storage. It is controlling a lamp. Maybe i'll program it to flash one time whenever a random packet arrives. I wonder how often that happens (because of broadcasts). I have tried different speeds for sending. Once every few days to 10 times a second. Is there any router setting that i should check? It's all on the local network though...

Comment: There shouldn't be any settings having anything to do with intranetwork UDP traffic. Are you sure that the transmitted packet will always have a null terminated C string in it? That the `\0` byte at the end of the string is transmitted in the packet. If it's not then your code is at the mercy of whatever happens to be on the stack - `receiveBuffer` isn't guaranteed to be zeroed, and it's possible that the `strstr()` call isn't being passed a null terminated string and is doing something unpredictable. Off the top of my head I don't remember whether netcat will null terminate a string.